# Strikeout entire row in Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to strike out entire row in Datagridview. This is what I'm doing currently:

```
 DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
 style.Font = new Font(dgview.Font.OriginalFontName, 7, FontStyle.Strikeout);              
 dgview.Rows[dgview.RowCount - 1].DefaultCellStyle.ApplyStyle(style);
```

This approach only strikes out the part of cells that have any text in them. What I'd like is to have a continuous strikeout i.e a single line that runs across the row.

I'd appreciate any help on this. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Saw this as probable answer in another question- "Probably the easiest way to do this, if all the rows are the same height, is to apply a background image to it that just has a big line through the center, the same color as the test."

If everything else fails then I'd go with this. But isn't there anything more simple?

EDIT2: Implemented Mark's suggestion with a bit of tweaking. The cellbound property wasn't working properly for me so I decided to get the location by using the rowindex and rowheight.

```
  private void dgv_CellPainting(object sender,DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            if (dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Strikeout"].Value.ToString() == "Y")
            {
                e.Paint(e.CellBounds, e.PaintParts);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 2), new Point(e.CellBounds.Left, gridHeaderHeight+ e.RowIndex * rowHeight+ rowHeight/2), 
                    new Point(e.CellBounds.Right, gridHeaderHeight+ e.RowIndex * rowHeight+ rowHeight/2));
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you create an event handler for `datagridview_CellPainting`, then `DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e` has everything you need.

For example, you can find out the row/column of the cell currently being painted (`e.RowIndex`, `e.ColumnIndex`).

So you can use this to determine if the current cell is the one you want to modify. If it is, you can try the following:

```
e.Paint(e.CellBounds, e.PaintParts);  // This will paint the cell for you
e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Blue, 5), new Point(e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Top), new Point(e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom));
e.Handled = true;
```

This will draw a thick blue diagonal line, but you get the idea... e.CellBounds also has Height/Width so you can easily calculate the middle to draw your line.

You can also change things like `e.CellStyle.BackColor` if you want more than just a line.

Comment: but then how do I get the starting and ending point to draw the line?

Comment: sorry but your answer is pretty vague and of no help at all. There is no way to get the starting and ending points to draw the line across the row

Comment: Please see more detail above.

Comment: @Arcturus Mark gave you a good hint.if you only had googled a little or take a look at msdn you would have found the additional information yourself.

Comment: My bad Mark. I tried what you'd earlier suggested on Grid Paint. Just skipped my mind that I could handle cellpaint the way you mentioned and get co-ordinates for each cell of the row rather than trying for the start and end of each row. Again sorry for the way I came across. @Wowa I knew about how to draw the line in a cell but got stuck in the "entire row" mindset. pretty dumb of me and yes it was a great hint in hindsight :)

Comment: No worries! Glad it helped. Apologies if my initial answer was a bit brief - I was not at my usual PC and was unable to clarify the details, so could only give a hint rather than the whole picture.

Comment: Gives unexpected results. here is my code snippet inside cellpainting: if (e.RowIndex != -1)
            {
                if (dgvIndividualRaceDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Strikeout"].Value.ToString() == "Y")
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 1), new Point(e.CellBounds.Left, (e.CellBounds.Top + e.CellBounds.Height) / 2), new Point(e.CellBounds.Right, (e.CellBounds.Top + e.CellBounds.Height) / 2));
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }

Comment: continuing...  This gives me a straight red line but unfortunately the location is way-off(instead of 11th row it shows in 5th). Seems like I'd have to do some trial and error.

Comment: Looks like the Y-coordinate doesn't give the exact location and I'd have to offset it by some value? Ah yes. The Y value is relative to form. So I've to factor in the Header on form and the grid column header as well. That would do the trick I think

Comment: Are you doing `(Top + Height) / 2`? Surely you want `Top + (Height / 2)` ?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells["RemovedBy"].Value.ToString()))
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Strikeout);
```