# How to paint a line on a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

How to paint a line on a datagrid, I'm trying like this but is not working.
the "row" variable is always null Falor...

```
    private void PersonData()
    {
        foreach (SingleEstoqueEntrada item in DataGridEstoque.ItemsSource)
        {
            try
            {
                var row = DataGridEstoque.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(I) as DataGridRow;
                if (item.ESTOQUE == 0.00m)
                    row.Background = Brushes.Pink;
                else
                    row.Background = Brushes.YellowGreen;
            }
            catch (Exception _Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(_Exception.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strikeout entire row in Datagridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826915/strikeout-entire-row-in-datagridview)

Comment: @DJKRAZE Not at all. It is winforms, here wpf.

Comment: @user3270570 - Where have you place this code? Row will be generated only when it gets rendered on UI. If you place this code in constructor of your UserControl/Window it won't work.

Comment: this could be easily done with `DataTemplate.Triggers`.  share your template may we have a look.

Answer (score 1):

if the data is properly binded and there is a property `ESTOQUE` as mentioned (also assumed from the code), placing this style in the resources may perhaps give the desired effect

```
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="YellowGreen" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ESTOQUE}"
                         Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="Pink" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

sample xaml

```
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="YellowGreen" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}"
                                 Value="item 1">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="Pink" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}"
                                Header="A Column" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Length}"
                                Header="Length" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <sys:String>item 1</sys:String>
        <sys:String>item 2</sys:String>
        <sys:String>item 1</sys:String>
        <sys:String>item 2</sys:String>
        <sys:String>item 2</sys:String>
        <sys:String>item 2</sys:String>
    </DataGrid>
```

result

[image: result]

in above example I wrote trigger to modify all rows which have `item 1`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var row = DataGridEstoque.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item)as DataGridRow;
```

instead of

```
var row = DataGridEstoque.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(I) as DataGridRow;
```

Comment: What Rohit mentions above: the item is not there until the control is loaded. Try putting this code in the Loaded() handler.